# How to limit the consecutive occurrences of elements in string using python regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have string with repetition of characters. If I want to limit the repetition what would be my pattern?

e.g.
suppose my string is `"aaaaajkefhejkffdddddrhigjlkglhhhh"` .
I want a output `aajkefhejkffddrhigjlkglhh.MOre` than 4 consecutive repetitions
should be replaced by two occurrences.

I tried the below piece of pattern.

```
str1=re.sub(r'(\w)\1+',r'\1{2}',str1)

str1="aaaaajkefhejkffdddddrhigjlkglhhhh"

import re
str1=re.sub(r'(\w)\1+',r'\1{2}',str1)
print (str1)
```

I expect the output `"a{2}jkefhejkf{2}d{2}rhigjlkglh{2}"` but the actual output is `"aajkefhejkffddrhigjlkglhh"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re

str1="aaaaajkefhejkffdddddrhigjlkglhhhhzzz"
str1=re.sub(r'(.)\1{3,}', r"\1\1",str1)
print(str1)
```

**Output:**

```
aajkefhejkffddrhigjlkglhhzzz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = "aaaaajkefhejkffdddddrhigjlkglhhhh"

def duplicate_character_shortener(input,length):
    index = 0
    while index<len(input)-length+1:
        if input[index:index+length]==input[index+1:index+length+1]:
            input = input[:index] + input[index+1:]
        else:
            index+=1
    return input

output = duplicate_character_shortener(input,2)
print(output)
>>> aajkefhejkffddrhigjlkglhh
```